# ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute duplicates sql output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am a newbie to rails and i needed to execute some sql query and output it to the view. In my controller i used something like "`@prob = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("...")` and then simply displayed the @prob in the view. However the output in the view keeps coming twice as 0 result column name result .

The sql query was

```
 @cprob = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT DISTINCT cause FROM pages LIMIT 2")
```

and my application environment is

```
Ruby version    1.8.7 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version    1.3.6
Rack version    1.0
Rails version   2.3.5
Active Record version   2.3.5
Active Resource version 2.3.5
Action Mailer version   2.3.5
Active Support version  2.3.5
Application root    C:/Users/Prateek/BitNami RubyStack projects/noc
Environment development
Database adapter    sqlite3
Database schema version 20100616055513
```

Update : - I found out that the oputput for ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute is actually an array containing hashes like {:0 => queryresult  :columnname => queryresult}

so how do i get just the queryresult from this

Comment: What is the output of "SELECT DISTINCT cause FROM pages LIMIT 2" when you run it directly on the SQlserver ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executed

```
`@users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM users")`
```

in my controller and get user names as

`<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <td><%=h user[1] %></td>
  <% end %>`

in view

Hope it'll help you to solve your problem

Comment: No, i simply used ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql query) in the controller for that model.